# What is the default order of files returned using mget?

Tags: sftp

When doing mget against a directory, such as being done below, what is the order the files are returned? I believe I'm seeing them in date/time order, and I just need to confirm this. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any pages that talk about this.

```
lcd sftp-archive/${remoteDir}/MenuMixExport
mget ./${remoteDir}/MenuMixExport/MenuMix_${locationCode}_*
```

Comment: If the order matters then maybe there's an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. What is it?

Comment: I have an older process that uses mget to bring files from FTP server.  I wrote a new python process to use paramiko to get the files.  date/time is embedded in the filename.  There were 2 files that were written to the FTP directory in reverse order to what the filename suggests.  Python code sorted on filename resulting in the 2 processes running the files in opposite order.  I am trying to confirm the 
default order for mget so I can ensure my python sorts in same order.  This issue occurred only once I can't move to the new code until I resolve how to prevent this issue going forward.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. FTP or SFTP? In the man page for SFTP, there is explicit mention that the results of `ls` are sorted lexicographically by default. I can't find anything that specifies an order for file retrieval. In the man page for FTP, there appears to be no mention of order. Thus, it is likely that it is unspecified, or varies by implementation. So, you should not rely on it. Use client-side sorting to get them in the order you require.

Comment: See [In what order does sftp fetch files when using “get -r folder”?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/506787/119732).